# SQL Server Log Shipping - individual folders for backups, or all in the one place?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

When setting up log shipping for an active/passive environment, I always try to keep the files neat, by dumping the log backups into their own folders:

`C:\TransLogs\Database1\`
`C:\TransLogs\Database2\`
`C:\TransLogs\Database3\`

etc. However a database server I came to manage today has five database log shipping files all dumped into `C:\TransLogs\`.

**Not all databases are shipping to the same secondary instances**

Apart from being a mess, is there any advantage into splitting them into their own folders? Should I spend my time cleaning it up, or is it safe to leave it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing log shipping for years now, and I haven't bothered to break them up into their own folders.  On one server I have 35 databases, all log shipping and all going to a single logship location.  No problems.